# MATLAB how to plot a vector of probability densities on to a histogram?

Tags: matlab, vector, histogram, probability-density, bins

I currently have a vector of calculated probability densities, i.e.

probden = (0.0008, 0.0016, 0.0048, 0.0064, 0.0072, ... , 1.0936, ... , 0.0072, 0.0064, 0.0048, 0.0016, 0.0008)

The list of calculated probability densities should be in the shape of a normal distribution.

I also have a same length list of the bins of each probability density.

I am trying to create a histogram such that each probability density is reflected on each bin on the X-axis.

If I use the function hist, it only shows how many probability densities are in each bin.

How should I go on approaching this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that goes hand in hand with `hist` is [`bar`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/bar.html)

In your case, you already have your histogram/distribution values (so no need to call `hist`), you can directly call `bar`:

```
bar( YourvectorOfBins , probden )
```